# Would there be memory overflow when using linked list with nodes in C? And does it happen usually?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, linked-list, nodes

I'm working on a programming exercise which concentrates on the use of linked list in C, and this is how I defined a node struct and some functions to work with it:

```
typedef struct log{
    struct log* next;
    long time;
    int status;
    char plate[];
}log;
```

```
log* init_lg(long t, int st, char pl[])
{
    log* p = (log*)malloc(sizeof(log));
    p->time = t; p->status = st; strcpy(p->plate, pl);
    p->next = NULL;
    return p;
}
```

```
void ins_lg(long t, int st, char pl[])
{
    if (lg == NULL)
    {
        lg = init_lg(t, st, pl);
        return;
    }
    log* i = lg;
    while (i->next != NULL) i = i->next;
    i->next = init_lg(t, st, pl);
}
```

However, I find out that the `ins_lg` function can't work properly with the `pl[]` string argument having the length of more than 7.

I can't reduce the size of that `pl[]` argument as its length must be higher than 7 due to the input data, sadly. So would there be a good solution for this?

For example, I tried that with `pl[]` being "1234567" and it ran well, but when I changed the `pl[]` into "12345678", it seemed falling into a frozen state and gave out an process-returning code of -1073740940 after a quite long delay.

I thought the problem might only be memory overflow, as I tested all the functions and they worked well with shorter (and smaller of course) values for the arguments.

Comment: `char plate[];` doesn't do what you think it does, google "flexible array member". You either have to allocate more memory (`malloc(sizeof(log) + size_of_your_string);`), or use `char *plate` instead and malloc the string separately.

Comment: You're not allocating any memory for `p->plate` before you execute `strcpy(p->plate, pl)`, which means you're overwriting memory you don't own.

Comment: Also learn how to enable the address sanitizer to be able to catch errors like those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plate` member has no size specified.  Given that it's the last member of a `struct`, that makes it a *flexible array member*.

Such a member doesn't actually have any space put aside for it, so `malloc(sizeof(log))` doesn't allocate any space for this member.  This means that any write to `plate` is writing past the end of allocated memory, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You would need to allocate enough space for the string you want to store in addition to the struct itself:

```
log* p = malloc(sizeof(log) + strlen(pl) + 1);
```